# What do employers do with the money they withhold for your income tax?

Tags: united-states, taxes

As per the rules, every employer withholds money from your paycheck for your income tax. These taxes are only paid once a year.

What do employers do with the money they've withheld from you in the meantime? Where do they deposit it?

Comment: This might be answered better on http://money.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is probably a better question for [Money.se]

Comment: @teja: Why do you believes taxes are "only paid once a year"? You only need to _file_ taxes once a year, but the tax withheld by the employer must be passed on to the IRS (almost) immediately.

Comment: Answer from [Personal Finance SE](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/63329/how-do-payroll-deducted-taxes-get-sent-to-the-irs)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with navigating the workplace.

Answer (score 11):

In the US, amounts withheld from income for taxes [must be passed to the IRS on either a monthly or semi-weekly basis](https://www.irs.gov/Businesses/Small-Businesses-&-Self-Employed/Depositing-and-Reporting-Employment-Taxes).

Answer (score 6):

While I suppose this may vary from country to country, everywhere I know of that employers withhold tax, they send it regularly to the government. For example here in Canada, I pay my staff twice a month. Once a month I must send these "withholdings" - tax, employment insurance, government pension - to the government. (I can "kite" a little by paying someone their net pay on the 15th and not having to send the withholding to the government for a few more weeks, but that's all.)

I have other "withholdings" that are not tax, such as paying premiums on private health insurance, and I use these to pay those bills each month. I'm sure it's the same for your employer. Also, here, if I withhold $1000 from you for the government and don't send it to them, that doesn't matter to you. Once I've told them (on your T4 tax slip that summarizes your income) that I withheld it for you, you get credit for it even if I fail to ever send it in.

As a result, you don't really need o know what your employer does with it.

Comment: There are some limited situations where the taxation authorities can come after the employee. Usually it's where the employee has some control over what happens with the amounts that should be withheld.

Comment: Perhaps in the US. I have experience with getting VERY behind on withholdings as an employer and such a thing was never mentioned (and we employ our shareholders.)

Comment: "In addition, if the employer refuses to withhold employment taxes from these wages and the IRS is unable to collect the employment taxes from the employer, the employee still has the responsibility to pay income tax and is ultimately responsible for his/her share of the FICA tax". It happens in Canada too. They will get their 454g of flesh somewhow.

Comment: Oh I withheld (reduce their paycheque) I just didn't send the withheld amount to the government, because I never had it. There was no impact on my staff of that, I was just running up a debt to the feds.

Comment: If the money 'withheld' is used to pay suppliers and employees, and it ends up nothing is left after the company goes -up, they can and will go after certain employees- someone like a bookkeeper (and especially the management). I would be cautious if I knew or suspected the money was not being remitted, is all I'm saying.

Comment: Should the debt become unrecoverable, sure. But up until that point, it's no problem, and even after that point it will never be a problem for someone who literally doesn't even know what happens to the money after it's withheld. Since we did eventually pay that debt back, all was fine in our case.

Comment: @KateGregory sounds like the IRS Is stricter than HMRC is in the UK  I have had a company go bust having not paid my NI (social security)  - turns out I couldn't claim unemployment benefits.

Answer (score 3):

In the U.S. -- they don't "deposit" it.  They make payments to the IRS, either through their bank (all business banks have this facility) or by having the IRS debit their accounts.  Some do this after *each* payroll period, and it's a very large amount of money if the company's big.  A similar approach applies for the state taxes.  Both IRS and the states really avoid the occurrence of employers making a lump-sum payment at the end of the year, because the employer's less likely to have the money after sitting on it for so long.